# CXF: JSON and XML response based on Content-Type

Tags: cxfrs

I am using the cxf and configured as follows:

'    <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
        <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
    </jaxrs:extensionMappings>'

So, i have verified that the content headers are right and the response to the interceptor is returned as the xml but after that client always getting the JSON response irrespective of header...

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I recently converted the Jersey json-from-jaxb example to work with CXF:
https://github.com/gmazza/jersey-samples-on-cxf/blob/master/json-from-jaxb/README.html

Client calls (tested with curl) requesting JSON and XML work without problem.  You may wish to inspect that sample and compare to any differences with yours to see the issue.